# JSF h:Link Navigation rule 404

Tags: html, xml, jsf, xhtml

I have this structure:

[image: xhtml structure]

In my header.xhtml i have a h:link like this:

```
<h:link value="Login page" outcome="account" />
```

And this navigation rule in the faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>account</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/users/accountIndex</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

But when a click the link i get 404, i dont understand... try to change de web.xml and/or the faces-config.xml but i get nothing...

This is the url of the h:link:

```
http://localhost:8080/catastrophes-system-web/faces/users/accountIndex
```

And here my web.xml for the mapping:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your using both the servlet mapping and prefix mapping may be confusing the servlet. From the spec.:

> JSF implementations must support web application that define a 
>   that maps any valid url-patternto the FacesServlet.**Prefix or extension mapping may be used**

You should either stick to the extension mapping or include *faces* in the faces-config navigation rule

Comment: Change extension mapping but now `http://localhost:8080/catastrophes-system-web/users/accountIndex.xhtml` get java.io.FileNotFoundException